# for-loop for R script based on the input file data

Tags: r, for-loop

The below R code works.

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- read.csv('./data.csv')
qplot(d$Time,d$Y)
ggsave(file='./test.png', dpi=300, w=4, h=3)
```

data.csv is as follows.

| Time | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.4 |
| 2 | 3.0 |
| 3 | 4.4 |
| 4 | 5.0 |
| 5 | 8.4 |
| 6 | 9.0 |

##########################

If the data-all.csv would be like below, I want to make a figure for each person.

| Time | Y | person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2.4 | John |
| 2 | 3.0 | John |
| 3 | 4.4 | John |
| 4 | 5.0 | John |
| 5 | 8.4 | John |
| 6 | 9.0 | John |
| 1 | 1.4 | Nancy |
| 2 | 2.0 | Nancy |
| 3 | 3.1 | Nancy |
| 4 | 3.9 | Nancy |
| 5 | 8.1 | Nancy |
| 6 | 8.8 | Nancy |
| 1 | 3.4 | Bob |
| 2 | 4.2 | Bob |
| 3 | 5.4 | Bob |
| 4 | 6.9 | Bob |
| 5 | 7.7 | Bob |
| 6 | 8.2 | Bob |

Of course, I can make the R code as below with the three divided data-all.csv, but I want to work the same procedure using for-loop or similar procedures in case I have a very large number of persons in the file.

The data-all.csv consists of only three persons, but I want to use the similar file consisting of more than 100 persons.

Similar questions might be published on the Web, but I am not so familiar with R and I could not make the R code I want.

I would appreciate it if you show me the code.

```
library(ggplot2)

d <- read.csv('./data-all_John.csv')
qplot(d$Time,d$Y)
ggsave(file='./test_John.png', dpi=300, w=4, h=3)

d <- read.csv('./data-all_Nancy.csv')
qplot(d$Time,d$Y)
ggsave(file='./test_Nancy.png', dpi=300, w=4, h=3)

d <- read.csv('./data-all_Bob.csv')
qplot(d$Time,d$Y)
ggsave(file='./test_Bob.png', dpi=300, w=4, h=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
library(ggplot2)


d <- read.csv('./data-all.csv')
for(pers_i in unique(d$person)){
  d_i <- d[d$person == pers_i, ]
  qplot(d_i$Time,d_i$Y)
  ggsave(file=paste0('./test_', pers_i, '.png'), dpi=300, w=4, h=3)
}
```

Comment: I deeply appreciated your quick and kind response!!!!!